# AspNetCore.Components.Forms.DataAnnotation - Blazor component- How to skip Validation on select properties?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Hi have several data entry forms bound to a **CUSTOMER** object. All fields on the object are marked required like this.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastName")]
    public string LastName
```

I have the data entry fields spread out between 5 forms. **I need to validate ONLY the current objects on the form, on the Submit.**

My form looks like this

```
<EditForm Context="formContext"
          Model="Customer"
          OnValidSubmit="SaveCustomer">
    <!-- This will validate the form -->
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <!-- This will show any validation errors -->
    @*<ValidationSummary />*@
<ul class="validation-errors">

    @foreach (
        var message in formContext.GetValidationMessages())
        {
            <li class="validation-message">@message</li>
        }
</ul>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            <label for="LastName">Last Name: </label>
            <InputText id="LastName" class="form-control"
                       @bind-Value="Customer.LastName" />
```

**When I submit the form. The customer objects on the other pages get validated as 'Required'. 
How do I skip the other customer fields. Like skip  the CUSTOMER PHONE field/property - because it's on another page/component.**

I have tried the following with no luck. Any ideas

```
@foreach (
            var message in formContext.GetValidationMessages().Where(x => !x.Contains("PHONE")))
            {
                <li class="validation-message">@message</li>
            }
    </ul>
```

Comment: IMO the proper way is to use a sub model.