# Naming a ViewModel in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Well, I just started working on the Blazor Server and started thinking about naming a **ViewModel**. We all know what a ViewModel is and this thread is all about just the naming convention in Blazor.

Since the components/views are referred to as **Pages** in Blazor, would it be appropriate to name a ViewModel as **PageModel** in Blazor or would it conflict with the [PageModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in **ASP.NET MVC Core**?

The following is an example for a Blazor component (page) called **Employee**,

```
public class EmployeePageModel 
{
    public string EmployeeID {get; set;}
    public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
}
```

Now the question is, whether the Model should be named as **EmployeeViewModel** or **EmployeePageModel** according to the Microsoft's convention.

Comment: Just a side note: In Blazor a simple page (SPA) can have several "ViewModels": https://stackoverflow.com/q/61282525/842935

Answer (score 0):

Actually, not all components/views are referred to as pages. Although all are .razor files, only those with an `@page` directive and a url route (simply the ones that are accessible with a url as a web page) are referred to as pages.

About your question; I wouldn't name a ViewModel something else. Naming conventions are used to clearify what is what, when someone else (or you in the future) reads the code later. If I see some classes named ViewModel, I don't need to think twice about what it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also don't name components the same name as Domain models. Example if you have a model by the name of "Entity" don't name the component Entity.razor, I had endless errors with the pages not loading. Until I changed the name of the component to "NewEntity" and it worked.